# VSTest 2013 Agent Stopped Working After First Test

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, vstest

We have been running into an issue where we are running our interactive Coded UI tests, and when our second test starts, the QTAgent32.exe stops working. Our setup is through TFS where we queue a new build that tells a controller to run our tests on VMs. These tests are directly sent to the VMs designated by a .testsettings file. Once the tests are distributed on the VMs, the tests start to work on the WPF application under test. A test can mainly take an hour to run due to the complexity of what needs to be tested. After the test completes and the agent shows '1/10 Completed' we get a windows message that QTAgent32.exe has stopped working.

- Problem Event Name: BEX
- Application Name: QTAgent32_40.exe
- Application Version: 12.0.21005.1
- Fault Module Name: StackHash_83e2
- Fault Model Version: 0.0.0.0

If we close out the Windows message, another will pop up with different details.

- Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
- Application Name: QTAgent32_40.exe
- Application Version: 12.0.21005.1
- Fault Module Name: msxml6.dll
- Fault Model Version: 6.30.7601.18431

If we close the second message, the test will be claimed as complete with a failure in the test results. We also see that the Agent will continue running the next test until it fails on the fourth test!

We have looked at event viewer on both the controller and agents. The controller shows nothing. The agent shows failures with the same details as the errors above. We have repaired the agent and looked into .Net. We know that we can run these tests in any order and that they do all pass without this issue when ran locally. The errors described above are only when ran on our VMs/Agents.

Anyone have ideas on how to either get more details during the test runs? Has anyone else ran into an issue like this before?

Thank you all in advance for taking a look and helping out!

Comment: It looks like [BEX indicates a buffer overflow exception](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/problem-event-name-bex-error-message/cf5baf73-0877-4070-abfb-a2c3a17a9e10#ThreadAnswers). Try checking your DEP settings on your VM vs your dev box (Control Panel > System Properties > Advanced > Performance Settings > Data Execution Prevention.

Comment: A variation in OSes or running as administrator vs not in those different environments might make a difference too. And if you're running web browser based tests, check on your internet explorer security settings (even Chrome uses some of those).

Comment: Thanks NextInLine! Will look more into the BEX settings. The OSes are the same, we run everything with administrative privileges and UAC off. Also, No web based tests, all WPF/C#.

Comment: To get more details on a test run, try [Enabling Coded UI Test Logs](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=880) if you haven't already.

Comment: Looks like DEP is required for the Agent executable and sub programs. When trying to add it to the exclusion list it requests throws an error saying it is required. Turned on logs and got no errors or warnings.

Comment: NextInLine, thank you so much for all of your help. After much investigation on our tests and what the VMs were doing, we learned that they were failing on the msxml6.dll. We were able to repair the installation for msxml6.dll and everything went back to working condition! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear. Debugging that kind of issue can be quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation and NextInLine's help, we found that the issue was with how our test was accessing and using the msxml6.dll. We repaired the installation of this dll and others, and resolved the issue.